# Detecting incoming and outgoing calls in android API29+

Tags: android, android-service, android-permissions, android-broadcast, telephonymanager

There are many questions about detecting incoming and outgoing calls in android, but all of them are old and also android deprecates the useful functions, and google play rejects my application because I'm using them.

For detecting outgoing calls I used:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

and also listening to `android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` broadcast listener.

According to the google document([this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) we should use `CallRedirectionService` and `CallScreeningService`. but these services work on API 29+.

So is there any way to detect Incoming and outgoing calls that don't deprecate and don't use sensitive permissions?

I want to close my socket connection if there are any calls and reopen it if not.

Comment: As per me i don't think there is a way to detect calls without sensitive permissions. I recently developed app and i archived the same via `android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS` permission but at the end google rejected my app due to using `android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS` more sensitive permission. They want strong reason to use such permission.

Answer (score 8):

You need a BroadcastReceiver for [`ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)
This will call your received whenever the phone-state changes from idle,ringing,offhook so from the previous value and the new value you can detect if this is an incoming / outgoing call.

A required permission would be `"android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"`

But if you also want to receive the `EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER` in that broadcast, you'll need another permission: `"android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"`

here's the receiver definition for your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="PhoneStateReceiver"> 
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>    
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And the code something like this:

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What about out going calls?

Comment: this code detects both incoming and outgoing, if the state changes idle => ringing you know it's an incoming call, if the state changes idle => offhook, you know it's an outgoing call

Comment: @marmor I'm not able to get this `BroadcastReceiver` in Android 13 is there any way to detect incoming and outgoing call above android 13 or can we detect or it's removed from 13 as suspicious permission?

Answer (score 5):

@marmor answer is correct, I just want to complete it.

for reading phone state first we should add the permission to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

and in receiver class, we can get current state by reading intent like this:

```
intent.extras["state"]
```

the result of extras could be:

> RINGING -> If your phone is ringing
>
> OFFHOOK -> If you are talking with someone (Incoming or Outcoming call)
>
> IDLE -> if call ended (Incoming or Outcoming call)

With `PHONE_STATE` broadcast we don't need to use `PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS` permission or deprecated `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` action.

Comment: for every outgoing call first state I received is `OFFHOOK` and if the opponent person pick up my call that time I didn't get any state I'll get `IDLE` when  opponent person hang up my call. it is right or is there any way to get any state when we calling someone.  1)) for outgoing call senario `OFFHOOK`->`IDLE`.  2)) for incoming call senario `RINGING`->`OFFHOOK`->`IDLE` (if pick-up the cal)   `RINGING`->`IDLE`(if decline call)