# How do I know if BroadcastReceiver is working?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, incoming-call

I'm trying to do an app that can send to a web service the phone numbers (and the contact name only if it is already registered) from incoming calls, so I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62653720/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android-api29) here, and I implemented the answer as the follow way:

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public String phoneNumber;
public String contactName;
ShareUuid su = new ShareUuid();
String uuid;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving an Intent broadcast.
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        if (extras.getString("state").equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            phoneNumber = extras.getString("incoming_number");
            Log.e("PhoneNumber", "onReceive: "+phoneNumber);

            String nombre_prueba = contactExists(context, phoneNumber);
            Log.e("nombre_prueba", nombre_prueba);

            uuid = su.getUuid();
            Log.e("UUID - PhoneStateReceiver", uuid);

            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
            Cursor rCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                    new String[] {
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID},
                    null,null,null);

            String nombre = rCursor.getString(0);
            //new SendData(uuid, phoneNumber, nombre).execute();
            Log.e("rCursor", nombre);
        }
    }
}

public String contactExists(Context context, String number) {
    /// number is the phone number
    Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
            Uri.encode(number));
    String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            Log.d("Phone number ID", ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID);
            Log.d("Phone number DISPLAY_NAME", ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
            contactName = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID;
            return contactName;
        }
    } finally {
        if (cur != null) cur.close();
        contactName = "Número no registrado";
    }

    return contactName;
}
}
```

}

And there are no errors compiling, but when I receive a call this is not showing anything in the logcat or the "run" section, so, I don't know if it is already working, here is my intent-filter from Android Manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I think it was probably my error, so I followed this [tutotial](https://programandoointentandolo.com/2014/08/broadcast-receiver-android.html) for an SMS receiver, but it also doesn't show anything when I receive a SMS.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did u asked for runtime Permission?

Comment: @ADM No, I didn't, I searched right now and I found why my code doesn't work, anyway, the examples I found doesn't show the requestCode for each permission, just shows "STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE" for example instead the int value for that permission, if I put the string like that Android Studio marks it as an error, I only foun the int value for READ_PHONE_STATE, it's 369, do you know where I can find the others? I'm using READ_CALL_LOG, READ_CONTACTS, CALL_PHONE and INTERNET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot to asked for permissions in runtime, I added this in my onCreate and works perfectly:

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
    )!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)},
                REQUEST_PERMISSION_PHONE_STATE);
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS
    )!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)},
                REQUEST_PERMISSION_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG
    )!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{(Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)},
                REQUEST_PERMISSION_READ_CALL_LOG);
    }
```

I also modified my PhoneStateReceiver class, I had a lot of problems trying to get the contact name when the incoming number is already registered, I found some questions here on StackOverflow but unfortunately none of them helped me (they were deprecated solutions), finally I managed to make it work with the following code, I hope it will be helpful to someone else

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public String phoneNumber = "";
public String contactName = "";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

        if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING) && phoneNumber!=null){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Ringing State Number is - " + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            contactName = getContactName(context, phoneNumber);
           
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    if(phoneNumber == null){
        return null;
    }

    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[] {ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    if(cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String contactName = "Contacto no registrado";
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactName = cursor.getString(0);
    }
    if(!cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return contactName;
}
```

}